# Interacting with files from multiple directories via bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I generated a script that iterates through several .csv files, converting relevant files to UTF-8:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/user/prod/
charset="text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1"

for file in *.csv; do
    if [[ $(file -i "$file") == "$file: $charset" ]]; then
        iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 "$file" > "$file.new";
        mv -f "$file.new" "$file";
fi
done
```

That works, but what I'd really like is to iterate through files that reside in different paths. I tried to start by setting one path (rather than defining a current directory), but I couldn't get it to work:

```
#!/bin/bash

path="/home/user/prod"
charset="text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1"

for file in "$path/*.csv"; do
    if [[ $(file -i "$file") == "$file: $charset" ]]; then
        iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 "$file" > "$file.new";
        mv -f "$file.new" "$file";
fi
done
```

What's the best way to do this by setting the path? What about handling files (same extension) that reside in different paths?

Comment: Aside: If my answer failed to address your question in full, I would have appreciated a comment to that point so I could have extended it earlier.

Comment: I'll apologize for the lack of clarity. Your answer was great. However, my question was a two part question. 1) Getting the script to work with one path, and 2) Getting the script to work with an array of paths. I was able to  develop my own script for the array of paths, given your answer, but in fairness statox's answer was more complete.

Comment: Fair enough. @statox's answer needs one minor correction, but it's otherwise a very good fit for the entirety of the question, including the components I skimmed over..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already accepted the answer of @Charles Duffy but (if I understood well) your question is about having files in **different directories** so if you need to work with multiple csv files on multiple directories you can use the following snippet:

```
# array containing the different directories to work with
pathDir=("/foo/bar/dir1" "/buzz/fizz/dir2")

for dir in "${pathDir[@]}" # For each directory
do
    for file in "$dir/"*.csv; do # For each csv file of the directory

        if [[ $(file -i "$file") == "$file: $charset" ]]; then
            iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 "$file" > "$file.new";
            mv -f "$file.new" "$file";
        fi

    done
done
```

The `pathDir` variable is an array which contains the path of different directories.

The first `for` loop iterate through this array to get all the paths to check.

The second `for` loop as in the previous answer iterate through the files of the current tested directory.

Comment: Quoting on the outer loop is wrong. You need to make this `"${pathDir[@]}"`, or you're getting the exact same behavior you'd have with `${pathDir[*]}` -- string splitting, glob expansion, etc.

Comment: @Charles thanks for the heads-up I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You stop the glob from being expanded when you quote it in

```
for file in "$path/*.csv"; do
```

Instead, quote the expansion but not the glob:

```
for file in "$path"/*.csv; do
```